# Android studio strange spinner adapter error

Tags: java, android

Hello I am trying to use spinner dropdown list. But I get strange error while doing it here are the codes

**Naryste.java**

```
public class Naryste extends Activity {

    private ImageView image;
    private String[] states;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private TypedArray imgs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Senioras);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }
}
```

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    tools:context=".Naryste" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Pasirinkite"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




</LinearLayout>
```

**Strings**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">LoginRegister</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_login">Login</string>
    <string name="title_activity_register">Register</string>
    <string name="title_activity_naryste">Naryste</string>
    <string-array name="Senioras">
        <item>1 mėn</item>
        <item>3 mėn</item>
        <item>6 mėn</item>
        <item>12 mėn</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Vaikas">
        <item>1 mėn</item>
        <item>3 mėn</item>
        <item>6 mėn</item>
        <item>12 mėn</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Suauges">
        <item>1 mėn</item>
        <item>3 mėn</item>
        <item>6 mėn</item>
        <item>12 mėn</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Logcat**

```
06-02 11:33:37.912  24999-24999/com.tonikamitv.loginregister E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tonikamitv.loginregister/com.tonikamitv.loginregister.Naryste}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.Naryste.onCreate(Naryste.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` at `Naryste.java` line `30`

Comment: which is line 30 in this java code?

Comment: spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Comment: Have you defined your activity in your android manifest

Comment: Your `spinner` is `null`, what is the name of `xml file` that contain the Spinner (country_spinner)?

Comment: so dataAdapter must be null that's why you getting that exception

Comment: Yes <activity
            android:name=".Naryste"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_naryste" >
        </activity>

Comment: @JafarKhQ yes it is country_spinner

Comment: then check xml file the layout you are setting in setContentView is it correct

Comment: @Clairvoyant I saw mistake contentview is set to main. It should be naryste

Comment: @Clairvoyant Add answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: So kind of you added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your xml file whether you have set the layout file in setContentView method is correct or not for the Activity you are using spinner.